# AuthorizationException in Impala

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: AuthorizationException: User 'hdfs' does not have privileges to access: default.*
```

When I try and run this simple command in impala-shell:

```
show tables;
```

Does anyone know how I might get the required privileges? Thanks.

Edit: I've just found the Impala app in Hue - it scrolls the same message down the screen for the admin user.

Comment: Did you configured sentry in the cluster ?.

Comment: I've a feeling a colleague (on leave) might have.

Comment: How can I tell? I'm not convinced it is enabled.

Comment: Find the admin user of sentry and using that user, grant privileges to your user. The admin users are configured in the sentry config files. If you have cloudera manager, you can check from there also